# I am trying to implement a system where I allow users to upload photos and only their friends can access photo. How to restrict such access

Tags: amazon-s3, filesystems, cdn

When a user uploads his photos it will be stored on CDN or DFS. Once a link is generated on either of this approach and link becomes public any person will be able to acess that file. I want to enforce a user level restrictions.

For Eg If I have three users A,B and C and A & B are friends
If A uploads photos to my system only B should be able to see it. Even if C get the link it should restrict access to C.

How do I implement such restrictions

I Tried reading on CDN and DFS but could not find any user level access to implement the ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using CloudFront as your CDN provider, then you can use signed URLs to control access to private content (See [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html)). Alternatively, you can just use [S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) directly, with the caveat that they would no longer be served via CDN.

Both approaches allow you to have expiration on the URL, which reduces risk of URLs being shared.